# Stata generate by groups

Tags: stata

I have a very weird thing happening with my code. I have panel data set  with the panel id being *p_id* and I am trying to create a another variable by using panel_id. My code is this, where *p_id* is the panel id, *marital_status* of person observed in each time period and *x* is the variable I would want to create.

```
bys p_id: gen count =_N
bys p_id: gen count1 =_n
bys p_id: gen x= marital_status if count1 ==1
```

However when I do

```
tab x
```

I get different numbers for rows (row total does not change) each time I run this code. The numbers are pretty closely clustered, but I need to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Posting a reproducible example increases your chances of getting adequate help. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the lack of a reproducible example is poor practice, it is possible to guess at what is going on. The first line of code is not problematic, but the second two have the same effect as

```
bys p_id: gen x = marital_status if _n == 1
```

In words, the new variable contains marital status data **from the first observation in each group of observations** for distinct `p_id`. But sorting on `p_id` says nothing about sort order for the observations with the same `p_id` and that within-group sort order is not reproducible without some sufficient constraint. So the first observation could easily be different (unless naturally there is only one observation in each group), with the results you report.

Concretely, suppose that there are 3 observations for `p_id` 42. Then any of 6 possible orders of those observations is consistent with sorting on `p_id`. And so forth.

Presumably there is something special about one observation in each group. You would need to explain more about your data and what you want to get to allow fuller advice, but this problem is not a puzzle.